# how to pass error message to file after invoking execvp in C

Tags: io, c, error-handling

When I invoke `execvp` with a command and its arguments, sometimes the command is not legitimate.

For example, if I do this in my shell (bash shell) using my forked **SON** process:

```
$ ls ffdfdfd
```

then the output is:

```
$ ls: cannot access ffdfdfd: No such file or directory
```

Now, I want to pass that exact message to a file. I've tried with `perror`, this way:

```
void directErrors(char * arg)
{
    perror(arg);  // execute the problem to screen

    // now execute the problem to file

    FILE* myFile = fopen("errors.log", "a");

     if(myFile == NULL)
     {
         perror("fopen");
         exit(-1);
     }

     fprintf(myFile, "%s: %s\n", arg, strerror(errno));
     fclose(myFile);
}
```

but all it does is write that command `X` failed.

How can I direct the exact output that `execvp` got after its invocation?

In my code I invoke `execvp` like this:

```
executeCurrentCommand = execvp(*(arg)[0], *arg);
```

Comment: You've been asking several programming questions. Please note that programming questions are off-topic here (see our [faq]); this is a site primarily for users and administrators of unix-like systems. We defer to [so] for programming questions.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `exec` works by *completely replacing* your program with the program you are exec'ing.  So, no code you write after an exec() call will ever run:

```
execvp(cmd, args);
/* This code is never reached.  */
```

The only way `exec` calls ever return is if the command you are trying to invoke cannot be run: for example if you try to exec a non-existent file or a file without execute privileges.

In your case, the command (`ls`) *does* exist and so the exec *does* succeed... which means that no code after it will ever be run.  The `ls` command will generate the error message to stderr just as it always does.

If you want to capture the output of `ls` you'll have to be more fancy.  For example you can open a file for append to the log file, then use `dup()` to duplicate that as the stderr file descriptor, then do your exec call.  The new process will inherit that setting and all output that `ls` sends to stderr will get appended to the log.  If you want to capture both stdout and stderr, dup them both.  That's how the shell, etc. does it.

BTW, using `*(arg)[0]` looks very bizarre to me: why do you use that?  More reasonable would be `(*arg)[0]` (I would think).